# (Django and PIL) encoder error -2 when writing image file

Tags: python, django, python-3.3, python-imaging-library

I'm new in Django and currently I am working on a my first project. For the thumbnails I'm using sorl-thumbnails, but a strange error piss me off and cannot figure out from where is come from.

That what I try to do is to re-size a image and crop 165x165 with canvas. After that I'm sending the image to the server and save it with PIL. Everything working good in 90% of cases, but some time I receive a error with the following text - "encoder error -2 when writing image file" and "Suspension not allowed here" in the console. The exception is raised on the follow row:

```
{% thumbnail request.user.artist.get_avatar "50x50" crop="center" as im %}
```

The strange here is that when I change it from "50x50" to "55x55". Everything start working.

The pictures are always with the same size (165x165). I have checked in the media folder and the image is saved properly.
The python version which I use is python 3.3.2 ,the version for Pillow is 2.2.2 and Django 1.6. Аny help would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/169#issuecomment-15531026
https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/173
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600147/sorl-thumbnail-encoder-error-2-when-writing-image-file

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error when using it with sorl-thumbnail. After long time spend on Google, i have came with this simple solution. Actually the error comes from **PIL(python-pil)**. But for Ubuntu users, "pip install PIL" is no longer in service :(. But the coolest thing is we can get rid of this error by simple package python-imaging.

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging
```

hopes that you already installed python-pil and other dependencies mentioned in the sorl-thumbnail tutorial,

for sorl-thumbnail

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev
```

for python-pil

```
sudo apt-get install python-pil python-pil-doc python-pil-dbg
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41018959/1176671
I do it in my Django project, so hope it would help you with Django as well.